# res.render not rendering view, returns html text

Tags: node.js, jquery, express

Calling into express/node thus:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "GET",
            data: {names : names},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("ajax post success");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText + ' :: ' + jqXHR.statusText);
            }
        });
```

In express router.js:

```
app.get('/metrics/:title/:node/:metric', function(req,res) {
    console.log("received request " );
console.log(req.query.names);
    res.render('nltuning', {
        locals: {
            tdata : req.params.title,
            gdata : req.params.node,
            mdata : req.params.metric,
            ndata : req.query.names
        }
    } );
});
```

All console msgs are printing correctly, ajax success is printing. ajax shows html text in response.

and the view is not rendered. Same for POST, GET - why is it ?

if i type in the same url in a browser window, the view is rendered. any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I see that this line was missing: success: function(data) {
                    console.log("ajax post success");
                    
                    jQuery('body').html(data);
                },

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to show the new content after the ajax call, shouldn't there be any code which says the script to do so?
For example:

```
success: function(data){
        $('someElement').html(data);
    }
```

Comment: yep, just realized it after posting. But i have a followup question. How can i show the new view in a new tab ?  This doesnt seem to work :  jQuery('body').target = '_blank';

Comment: I haven't dealed with that problem before, but maybe that helps:  window.open('url to open','window name','attribute1,attribute2')  Open a new tab and put the "names"into the attributes, that won't be real ajax but at least it would work I'd say